# Xamarin forms, Plugin.InAppBilling, Android: Error after successful purchase

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase, cross-platform

I get an error after a successful purchase in Android (Xamarin forms, Plugin.InAppBilling). But the purchase was successful because I can see the revenue in the dashboard. My credit card was also charged.

This is my code:

```
try
        {
            var productId = "";
            var payLoad = "";

            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    productId = "removeAdd";
                    payLoad = "";
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                    productId = "removeadd";
                    payLoad = "payLoad";
                    break;
            }

            CrossInAppBilling.Current.InTestingMode = true;

            var connected = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.ConnectAsync();

            if (!connected)
            {
                //Couldn't connect to billing, could be offline, alert user
                return;
            }

            //try to purchase item
            var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.Subscription, payLoad);
            if (purchase == null)
            {
                //Not purchased, alert the user
            }
            else
            {
                //Purchased, save this information
                var id = purchase.Id;
                var state = purchase.State;

                Task task = AsyncTask();
            }
        }
        catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException purchaseEx)
        {
            //Billing Exception handle this based on the type
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            //Something bad has occurred, alert user
        }
        finally
        {
            //Disconnect, it is okay if we never connected
            await CrossInAppBilling.Current.DisconnectAsync();
        }
```

In MainActivity.cs:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        //inApp
        Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        InAppBillingImplementation.HandleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

The purchase variable is null and that is all. When I try to buy again, I get the message that I have already bought it. It is working for IOS.

Comment: what is "an error" specifically?  Are you getting an exception or some other error message?  Or are you saying that `PurchaseAsync` returns a null?

Comment: Hello Jason, PurchaseAsync returns null. Everything else worked, I get a popUp that the purchase was successful. I think that popUp is from the plugin itself.

Comment: you might try debugging HandleActivityResult to see what it is doing, but otherwise I'd suggest opening an issue on the plugin's github page